# Is it haram in Islam to read about sex?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

Can I read about sex? I mean is it allowed or is it halal to read about sex? Can we like read about sex if we are reading it for our knowledge?

Comment: Please make sure to turn on **[Safe Search](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1)** before you proceed. Please. Also stay away from images as much as you can.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is allowed to read about it, but only for specific purpose and pure intentions. If you want to understand about it from educational perspective and to develop your understanding to protect yourself from sex related harms or issues, then it is even recommended.

It would only be wrong if it leads you to commit any illegal sexual act. So it is better to read about sex from Islamic sources, as they dont have any explicit material in them, which may cause any problem